# Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $x+y = \frac{1}{a}$ and $y \leq \frac{1}{b} + x$, then analyse $x$ and $y$ range

Tags: real-analysis

I think I feel stupid right now. I would appreciate your confirmation. Please see below.

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$,
\begin{align}
x+y = \frac{1}{a} \tag{1},
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
y \leq \frac{1}{b} + x \tag{2}.
\end{align}

> What can we say about the range of $x$ and $y$?

---

- Using $(1)$, we can say $y = \frac{1}{a} - x$, then plugging in $(2)$, we can say that
  \begin{align}
   x \geq \frac{1}{2a} - \frac{1}{2b}.
  \end{align}
- Similarly, using $(1)$, we can say $x = \frac{1}{a} - y$, then plugging in $(2)$, we can say that
  \begin{align}
  y \leq \frac{1}{2b} + \frac{1}{2a}.
  \end{align}

What more to say?

> **Am I really making any mistake**?

Comment: Nothing more can be said. Note that if you take equality in the bounds you have obtained you will get a solution to the original system.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you so much for your confirmation.

Comment: Indeed, it is true that $x \geq \frac{1}{2a} - \frac{1}{2b}$ and $y \leq \frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{2b}$. In addition, it is also important to note that an arbitrary pair $(x, y)$ that satisfies this both of these inequalities does not necessarily satisfy both $(1)$ and $(2)$ because the constraint $x + y = 1/a$ is not guaranteed to be satisfied by these pairs. In other words, the constraint $x + y = 1/a$ still needs to be taken into consideration when working backwards.

Comment: @RoycePacibe Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and there is nothing more to say.

Note that $y$ is a (strictly) decreasing function of $x$ and vice-versa, so if $x$ and $y$ are both equal to their respective bounds, the two initial conditions should be satisfied.

Indeed, they are: if you set $x = \frac{1}{2a} - \frac{1}{2b}$ and $y = \frac{1}{2a} + \frac{1}{2b}$ you can easily see that

$$
x + y = \frac{1}{a}
$$

and that

$$
y - x = \frac{1}{b} \leq \frac{1}{b}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Given $$x+y= + 1/a~~~(1);~~ x-y \ge -1/b~~~(2)$$ Adding them we get  $$x\ge \frac{1}{2}(1/a-1/b)~~~~(3)$$. From (1) and (2) we get $$1/a-y=x\ge \frac{1}{2}(1/a-1/b) \implies y\le\frac{1}{2}(1/a+1/b).$$
Yes this is all you get (as you cannot subtract two inequalities which are in the same direction). With inequlity(s) options are limited.